# how to know email status (mailject)

Tags: c#, email, sendmail, mailjet

I'm using Mailjet SMTP to send email's. Now, i want to verify if email was send or not. Mailjet have this [email status](https://eu.mailjet.com/docs/email_status) , but how i can have access to this information? Mailjet have too this [API](https://eu.mailjet.com/docs/api), but this in php...

If i use `DeliveryNotificationOptions` can resolve this?
Something like this:

```
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess | DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure | DeliveryNotificationOptions.Delay;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can communicate with API Mailjet like:

```
Uri address = new Uri("http://api.mailjet.com/0.1/reportEmailsent");
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Headers.Add("apiKey", "numberapiKey");
request.Headers.Add("secretKey", "numbersecretKey");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("apiKey", "serialKey");
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
request.Accept = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
```

Now getting response:

```
// Get response
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
   Stream ResponseStream = null;
   ResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   int responseCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
   string responseBody = ((new StreamReader(ResponseStream)).ReadToEnd());
}
```